# DI / Unity OutOfMemoryException when running many tests in parallel

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, out-of-memory, unity-container

We have about 10K xUnit tests in Visual Studio / Windows / C# solution. The solution uses Unity DI.  Recently it started to produce *OutOfMemoryException* when all or a large portion of the tests are **run together in parallel**. Typical exception message looks like:

> Message: Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException : Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'ISomeService', name = '(none)'.
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: OutOfMemoryException - Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

but sometimes it could appear out of some low level database related code.

It is **NOT** a circular reference issue (which actually produces *StackOverflowException*, but not *OutOfMemoryException*) because if I rerun any of the failing tests one by one (or even in some small groups), then **all** of them pass.

I'd appreciate any advice regarding how to deal with that. All projects are built for AnyCPU and gcAllowVeryLargeObjects is not set.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The obvious solution is to run your tests in parallel *in small groups.*  You could also try adding more memory to your computer.

Comment: Are you properly disposing your services, connections etc?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I wish I knew. There are about 10K tests written mostly by some other people. However, most, if not all DB related stuff is wrapped into using and most of the services are singletons. The breaking change, I guess, was recent introduction of code based on InjectionFactory, like: container.RegisterType<ISomeType>(SomeStringKey, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),new InjectionFactory(c => new SomeType(getter))); Then the factory created objects should be disposed properly but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not out of computer memory. I am out of memory in tests. So adding more won't help. The fact that tests started to fail when run in a large group may point to some bigger problem, which then may surface in production. On another side it could be just test related. That's what I am trying to nail down.

Comment: `The breaking change, I guess, was recent introduction of code based on InjectionFactory` - that's a good starting point for understanding where the issue is

Comment: Also, consider using a tool like [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) to analyse the memory usage in your tests

Comment: `I am not out of computer memory` -- Fair enough.  The problem, then, is not physical memory, it is *large memory allocations.*  You still may need to run your tests in smaller batches, a technique you know already works.   Run a memory profiler, as Rui suggests.